# SharePoint 2010 Install with SQL Server 2008 Express which is missing agent service, SharePoint will work?

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-enterprise, sql-server

I am installing **SharePoint 2010** with **SQL Server 2008 R2 Express** on **Windows Server 2008 R2**.

During installation of SQL Server, I have noticed Agent service is not in the service list, I goggled and found it is not included in Express edition, If I proceed further without agent service will my SharePoint work normally?

Update: just finished with sql installation, agent service is installed but it was stopped by default. Any problem in future?

Answer (score 2):

i dont see any issue, but this kind of installation is meant for small stuff / demo things, because this type of installation has limitation as compare to regular sql version.
few limitations are(i am sure you know about this):

- You cannot install the single server with built-in database version
  of SharePoint Server on a domain controller.
- A SQL Server 2008 Express database cannot be larger than 4 GB.
- You cannot use User Profile Synchronization in a single server with
  built-in database installation.
  http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc263202(v=office.14).aspx

similar kind of post:
[Can I use a SQL Express database for sharepoint 2010?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/5568/can-i-use-a-sql-express-database-for-sharepoint-2010)

Answer (score 1):

this service is mainly used for jobs, like backing up database ect... if you have an updated version of SQL like 2012 than this service would be disabled...

> By default, the SQL Server Agent service is disabled when SQL Server
>   2012 is installed unless the user explicitly chooses to autostart the
>   service.

also note

> SQL Server Agent uses SQL Server to store job information. Jobs
>   contain one or more job steps. Each step contains its own task, for
>   example, backing up a database.
>
> SQL Server Agent can run a job on a schedule, in response to a
>   specific event, or on demand. For example, if you want to back up all
>   the company servers every weekday after hours, you can automate this
>   task. Schedule the backup to run after 22:00 Monday through Friday; if
>   the backup encounters a problem, SQL Server Agent can record the event
>   and notify you.

also like to note that sharepoint comes with SQL express version by default and that service is disabled by default. This service would be set to automatic on live (error logging and backup is vital on live) and disabled on test / dev enviroment (no need to waste resources)!

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189237.aspx